# Using regex to filter these specific chars ° * :

Tags: java, regex, alphanumeric

I need to allow these special chars to be saved in the DB ->  ° * : 
and I'm having troubles to know which part of the next string I have to remove to allow them.

```
private static final String ALPHANUMERIC_RE =  "^([\\w\\d_\\s\\,\\&\\/\\(\\)\\;\\\'\\\"#@\\$])*$";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `ALPHANUMERIC_RE = "^([\\w\\d_\\s\\,\\&\\/\\(\\)\\;\\\'\\\"#@\\$])*$"` can be shortened to:

`ALPHANUMERIC_RE = "^[\\w\\s,&/();'\"#@$]*$"`

They both behave the same, i.e. match strings containing the following chars:

- any alphanumeric char, case insensitive
- spaces and tabs
- `,`, `&`, `/`, `(`, `)`, `;`, `'`, `"`, `#`, `@`, `$`

Now, it's esaier to understand where you should add your new chars:

`ALPHANUMERIC_RE = "^[\\w\\s,&/();'\"#@$°*]*$"`

Comment: So using ALPHANUMERIC_RE = "[\\w\\s,&/();'\"#@$°*]*" would allow me to admit this chars +°: ?

Comment: @jose The one you gave will allow the chars `°` and `*`. But don't forget the `^` and `$` anchors.